# How to make gdb for a target and use it there

Tags: linux, gdb, embedded-linux

I am trying to compile gdb-8.2 from source.
**Build machine: x86-64

Host AND target: arm-linux-gnueabi**

I ran:

```
CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc ./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabi --target=arm-linux-gnueabi  
make
```

Then I ran:

```
make DESTDIR=<Some Path>/gdb_installation install
```

So I got a usr folder inside gdb_installation folder. I copied the usr/local/bin/gdb to my target and ran

```
./gdb
```

Output:

```
#./gdb  
#
```

But it does not show anything. It exits without any message.

What am I missing here?
Running the file command shows that the gdb executable is indeed built for my target.

PS: Running a sample hello world program using arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc works perfectly fine on the target; and file command shows the same output that it did for gdb.

Comment: FYI... GDB 8.3 is the latest (as of this writing). I know it has some important bug fixes for OS X.

Comment: You probably don't want to build this from source, at least not on its own.  You'd either use a prebuilt package, or build it as part of building an image for the target system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I missing here?

Your build looks correct, but doesn't work. It's not clear why, so you need to debug that.

1. What is the exit status of this `gdb` on the target?
   `./gdb --version; echo $?`
2. Does it actually do anything? 
   `strace ./gdb --version`
3. Is there anything interesting in the kernel message log?

Depending on answers to above questions, further guesses of what has gone wrong will be possible.

Perhaps there is some `.gdbinit` that tells GDB to quit? What does this do:
`./gdb -nx --version`?